# How custom authentication-provider works

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Good day people.

Please help. Can not understands how my custom authentication-provider should be triggered.

I have:

Spring-context.xml

```
<security:http pattern="/login" security="none" />  


            <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">


                <security:form-login login-page="/login"/>

                <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

                <security:form-login authentication-failure-url="www.google.com"/> 

            </security:http>



            <security:authentication-manager>

                <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userSecurityService"/>

            </security:authentication-manager>


            <bean id="webContentDAOImpl" class="demidov.pkg.persistence.WebContentDAOImpl">
                <property name="sessionFactory"><ref bean="sessionFactory"/></property>
            </bean>


            <bean id="userSecurityService" class="demidov.pkg.persistence.UserSecurityService">
                <property name="webContentDAOIF" >
                    <ref bean="webContentDAOImpl"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
```

Login Controller:

```
   @Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {

        return "login"; 
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/security/j_spring_security_check", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String  access() {

        return "redirect:/";

    }


}
```

Login JSP page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="security/j_spring_security_check" method="post">

        UserName: <input type="text"/> <br>
        Password: <input type="password"/> <br>

        <br>

        <input type="submit"/> 


    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Custom principal resolver:

```
   public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService{


    WebContentDAOIF webContentDAOIF;

        public WebContentDAOIF getWebContentDAOIF() {
            return webContentDAOIF;
        }


        public void setWebContentDAOIF(WebContentDAOIF webContentDAOIF) {
            this.webContentDAOIF = webContentDAOIF;
        }


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {


         UserDetails userDetails = null;


         TheUser theUser = webContentDAOIF.fetchUserByName(userName);

         userDetails = new User(theUser.getUserEmale(), theUser.getUserPassword(), true, true, true, true, getAthorities(theUser.getRoleAccess()));


        return userDetails;
    }


    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAthorities(String role) {


        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(2);


        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(" "));


        if ( role.equals("ROLE_USER")) {

            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
           }

           // Return list of granted authorities
           return authList;

    }   

}
```

I just can not understand how my custom principal resolver should work with security. How it should be triggered and by what??? When I put wrong username and password on login page it seems not work with my `UserSecurityService` and just simply redirect me on login page again because of my `hasRole(ROLE_USER)` in spring-context.xml . I believe that `j_spring_security_check` may do something, but so doubt of it. Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 3):

kindly refer to below mentioned link, may be of some help :-
      [spring security custom authentication](http://javahunter.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/spring-security-3-custom-authentication-manager/)

Comment: This link it how to make it work(how to build security), but I would like to know why my UserSecurityService does not been invoke and why. Commonly how it works?

Answer (score 0):

method `loadUserByUsername` is having param `userName` which is having value posted from browser that userName is compared with DB and password is fetched from DB and passed to `UserDetail` object which is having a password posted from browser so now it will compare the passwords internally and acts accordingly for authentication